# Header-only asio standalone

Tags: boost-asio

Sorry in advance for a kind-of-dumb question - I'm pretty new to all this.

So I downloaded asio from [here](http://think-async.com/), and tried to #include asio.hpp, but got the following error;

```
fatal error: boost/config.hpp: No such file or directory
```

I thought this was rather odd, as it was suppose to be independent of Boost. I poked around a bit, and saw that I needed to define ASIO_STANDALONE, which I promptly did, only to be met with more errors where it tried to #include something else from Boost.

Is there just a big list of all the things I have to #define to tell it to be standalone or something? That would be very helpful.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As noted on the Asio [website](http://think-async.com/Asio/AsioStandalone):

> When using a **C++11** compiler, **most** of Asio may now be used without a dependency on Boost header files or libraries. To use Asio in this way, define `ASIO_STANDALONE` on your compiler command line or as part of the project options.

Thus even when `ASIO_STANDALONE` is defined, Asio will use Boost when:

- Using a non-C++11 compiler.
- When using certain features, such as [stackful coroutines](http://think-async.com/Asio/asio-1.10.2/doc/asio/overview/core/spawn.html) that are based on the [Boost.Coroutine](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/coroutine/doc/html/index.html) library.

---

With [asio-1.10.2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/asio/files/asio/1.10.2%20%28Stable%29/), the following program:

```cpp
#include <asio.hpp>

int main()
{
  asio::io_service io_service;
}
```

compiles with gcc 4.8.1, using `-DASIO_STANDALONE -std=c++11` compiler flags.  Without specifying the compiler to use c++11, compilation fails when attempting to include Boost header files.

Comment: ...asio-1.10.2\include\asio\detail\impl\socket_ops.ipp|533|error: 'SO_UPDATE_CONNECT_CONTEXT' was not declared in this scope

Comment: Windows 7, 32 bit, Code::Blocks, GNU GCC, c++11, defined ASIO_STANDALONE, asio 1.10.2

Comment: @CharlesNoon Although that particular setup has not been officially tested, you could try using [asio-1.10.3](https://github.com/chriskohlhoff/asio/tree/asio-1-10-3) or pulling in [this](https://github.com/chriskohlhoff/asio/commit/c0d6ba03c86faa92adba0d58d208735e9f453161) commit as it removes the assumption that `SO_UPDATE_CONNECT_CONTEXT` has been declared for the Windows IOCP backend.

Answer (score 13):

This is an old question, however i had the same problem currenlty with Visual Studio 2013 and Asio 1.10.6. In Visual there is no switch nor compiler flag for c++11 features. 
 Even with `#define ASIO_STANDALONE`Asio requires Boost. 

 

 
Solution is to manually specify that our compiler is c++11 compliant. Just add:

```
#define ASIO_STANDALONE 
#define ASIO_HAS_STD_ADDRESSOF
#define ASIO_HAS_STD_ARRAY
#define ASIO_HAS_CSTDINT
#define ASIO_HAS_STD_SHARED_PTR
#define ASIO_HAS_STD_TYPE_TRAITS

#include <path_to_asio/asio.hpp>
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing, I also did this by just add those in the preprocessor definitions and there is no warnings.

Comment: Same problem in Visual Studio 2015 Update 2, using the same version of Asio. Even though it compiled and run correctly the intellisense still complained about boost. Adding the #defines removed all warnings/errors.

Comment: Is this still true? Seems like `boost/asio/io_service.hpp:25` breaks the standaloneness with `#include <boost/system/error_code.hpp>`

Comment: @RPGillespie Apparently, there are **two** versions of Asio: Boost.Asio and plain Asio. The former needs to be linked against Boost.System since it is a part of Boost. Refer to this page for details: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/doc/html/boost_asio/using.html.